# Reverting back to pure div after a few DOM additions

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a div that I created with html. In this dive I add a few elements with JavaScript. Then I clone the div into which I added these new elements. After the cloning process, I want the div I created with HTML to return to its pure state at the beginning of the page. How can I do this with JavaScript

I want to return to my fure HTML div.

Comment: Add the elements *after* cloning, not before. Then the original div will be left unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Before you add elements to the original div, save its `innerHTML` property to your own variable.

```
const originalDiv = document.querySelector('.div1')
const savedHTML = originalDiv.innerHTML
```

Then when you want to reset it to its “pure state”, just set `innerHTML` to the value in that variable.

```
originalDiv.innerHTML = savedHTML
```